# R: convert table to adjacency matrix or edgelist

Tags: python, r, matrix

I have the following table

```
1   "x1"    "x2"            
1   "x1"    "x2"    "x3"
1   "x1"    "x2"
2   "y1"    "y2"    "y3"
2   "y1"    "y2"    "y3"
3   "y1"    "x2"
3   "z1"    "x2"
```

I need to transform this table as an adjacency matrix or an edgelist where I can have the first column as an attribute of the edge, and the rest of the columns would be my edges, for example, I would need the lines that have more than 3 edges that they all get connected like this (for line 2):

```
"x1" "x2" 1
"x1" "x3" 1
"x2" "x3" 1
```

The one meaning the type of edge that I want.

Is there a way to do this in R or python?

I'm going to plot this with igraph in R.

Comment: do you mean "X2" "x3" 1 for the last bit of your line 2 example?

Comment: Yes yes, that's exactly it, I will update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find a simple transformation. But using your sample data:

```
dd <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), V2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("x1", "y1", "z1"), class = "factor"), 
    V3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("x2", 
    "y2"), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "x3", "y3"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

I ended up creating a few helper functions and using the `magrittr` syntax that `dplyr` likes to use to arrive at this

```
library(magrittr)

smoosh <- function(...) do.call(Map, c(list(cbind.data.frame), list(...)))
collpase <- function(x) do.call(rbind, x)
has.char <- function(x) x[nchar(x)>0]

xx <- dd[-1] %>% as.matrix %>% split( 1:nrow(dd)) %>% lapply(has.char) %>% 
    lapply(combn,2) %>% lapply(t) %>% smoosh(attr=dd$V1) %>% collpase
```

As you can see there were a bunch of small transformations which is why I chose to use the `%>%` operator for `magrittr` rather than nesting them all for readability. But in the end it returns

```
     1  2 attr
1   x1 x2    1
2.1 x1 x2    1
2.2 x1 x3    1
2.3 x2 x3    1
3   x1 x2    1
4.1 y1 y2    2
4.2 y1 y3    2
4.3 y2 y3    2
5.1 y1 y2    2
5.2 y1 y3    2
5.3 y2 y3    2
6   y1 x2    3
7   z1 x2    3
```

Comment: It's almost righ! The only problem that I got with the real data is that the attribute is always 1, it's not changing.

Comment: I don't see how that's a problem. What specifically would be different?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it right, when I have different attributes it would be required to keep the attributes, not change it to 1.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was my mistake, the script is fine!